# "freeze somebody out (of something)" and "freeze out somebody (of something)" and "freeze out (of something) somebody"?

Tags: word-usage

Just want to understand how to use [this structure](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/freeze-out)

**freeze somebody <--> out (of something)**: (informal) to be deliberately unfriendly to somebody, creating difficulties, etc. in order to stop or discourage them from doing something or taking part in something

so, "**out**" can be brought to before "**somebody**" right.

But I am not sure whether

*freeze me out of the conversation*= *freeze out me of the conversation* = *freeze out of the conversation me*

Answer (score 1):

*Freeze out* is a phrasal verb, i.e., it consists of two parts (here, a verb and an adverb), and it has an idiomatic meaning, to exclude.  Such constructs may take an *object*, which may precede or follow the adverb:

> In important decisions, don't **freeze out** *your spouse*.
>   In important decisions, don't **freeze** *your spouse* **out**.

But when the object is a *personal pronoun*, it can't take the position following the adverb:

> I'm your spouse.  Don't **freeze** *me* **out**.

"Don't **freeze out** *me*" is unacceptable.  Check [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verbs-multi-word-verbs).

Comment: Someone should have explained this to Morten Harket of A-Ha! with that whole "Take On Me" thing.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Although those lyrics are basically [gibberish in English](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51437), I’ve always theorised it was a deliberate verbatim translation from Norwegian, where _ta på mig_ means ‘touch me’, and _ta mig på_ means ‘put me on [like clothes]’. I think they were aware of the proper order of constituents in English; they just chose to ignore it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet well, "Take on me" is a more interesting title, which makes the viewer/listener do a sort of double take, so works well from that perspective.  In the lyrics, Harket does actually prove he knows the difference, as the chorus goes "Take on me, take me on", as if he's explaining the title.

Comment: @MaxWilliams That's what I meant—I've always seen the ‘reversed repetition’ as reflecting the Norwegian meanings, where it would make perfect sense. Sort of an inside joke for about 20 million people.

Answer (score 0):

Convention is to order it like so - "freeze me out of the conversation." You cannot say "freeze out me..." Or "freeze out of the conversation me" - it might *very, very technically* not be incorrect grammar, but it's a bizarre inversion of the sentence.